# How to update a single field in a capped collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, capped-collections

```
db.events.update(
   {upload:0},
   {$set:{upload:1}},
   {multi:true}
)
```

I am getting the following error even though I am just replacing an integer with another integer.

```
Cannot change the size of a document in a capped collection: 402 != 406
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not updating integer value `{upload:0}` to double value `{upload:1}` ? You can check the type by running  `db.events.find({upload: {$type: 'int'}})`  and see if it returns any document(s) for verification. Are you running queries in shell ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you're inserting a `double` instead of an `int32` (`double` is 4 byte wider than `int32`).

from [mongodb type documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/) :

> **NumberInt**
>
> The mongo shell treats all numbers as floating-point values by
>   default. The mongo shell provides the NumberInt() constructor to
>   explicitly specify 32-bit integers.

To fix this issue, simply change your code to this :

```
 db.events.update(
   {upload:0},
   {$set:{upload: NumberInt(1)}},
   {multi:true}
)
```